# Selecting `<option>` value from controller for `<select ng-options>`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

```html
<select
      class="form-control input-md
      availabiltyDatesInput pull-left"
      name="statusModel"
      autocomplete="off"
      id="statusModel"
      ng-options="alertStatus.value as alertStatus.text for alertStatus in alertStatuses"
      ng-model="statusModel">
 </select>
```

I have a Select with options. And I need that the value of this select will be pre populated.

I'm trying to set ng-model in controller:

```js
angular.module("app.alerts")
.controller("alertsCtrl", function ($scope, CarmateCommonApiSvc, $uibModal) {

     getLookupsData();

     var alertStatuses = [];

     function getLookupsData() {
        alertStatuses = [];

        CarmateCommonApiSvc.getLookups().then(function (res) {
            if (res.code != 0) return;
            _.each(res.data.allLookups, function (item, index, arr) {

                if(item.name == 'AlertStatus'){
                    alertStatuses.push(item);
                }
            });
            $scope.alertStatuses = alertStatuses;                
            $scope.statusModel = alertStatuses[0];
        })
     }
});
```

But it doesn't work.
I'm new in AngularJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ng-model with the value like this:

```
$scope.statusModel = alertStatuses[0].value;
```

For more information and examples check here: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Maybe you should check first if the array has any items:

```
if(alertStatuses.length > 0){
    $scope.statusModel = alertStatuses[0].value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`statusModel` should only be set as a single vale not the full object `alertStatuses[0]`. So, update your code like:

```
$scope.statusModel = alertStatuses[0].value || 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually abuse [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive.

```
<select
  class="form-control input-md availabiltyDatesInput pull-left"
  name="statusModel"
  autocomplete="off"
  id="statusModel"
  ng-options="alertStatus.value as alertStatus.text for alertStatus in alertStatuses"
  ng-model="statusModel"
  ng-init="statusModel = alertStatuses[0]"
>
</select>
```

Comment: Why advise people to abuse the `ng-init` directive when the AngularJS team recomends otherwise? Also the value of `ng-init` code is wrong because the `ng-option` specifies `alertStatus.value as alertStatus.text for alertStatus`.

Comment: I was bringing to notice another way to achieve OP's requirement. I also did mention that it is an abuse of the directive. Regardless of it being abusive, it is a viable method which should be acknowledged. I do agree that the value assigned is wrong.